# CURL timeout, no packet loss in PING

Tags: networking, ping

I'm trying to debug a problem with my Authelia acting as an OIDC provider. A Gitea instance tries to connect to `https://auth.mydomain.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` and fails with a timeout. When I run `curl` within the Gitea Docker container and also directly on the Debian server it's running on, I get

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to auth.mydomain.com port 443 after 130595 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

However, `ping` shows no packet loss and the correct public IP. Furthermore, `traceroute` returns mere 2 hops.

If I try to `curl` from my computer, I get the expected output – so I know that Authelia is up and running.

Could you help me figure out what's causing this behaviour, please?

Comment: Looks like the debian server has no access to the url. Does the domain resolve into the right IP address? Is the port 443 open? Test it with `telnet auth.mydomain.com 443`

Comment: timeout is a general error indicating that no response was received to a given HTTP request. it can be caused by firewalls that are configured to drop traffic with no response, or by broken services that do not respond at all to the request. generally speaking, abscent a firewall, WAF or request filtering configuration (anything that interfers with the connection with no reply at all), you will get a more specific error like a hostname lookup failure, port connect failure, connection refused/reset,  etc that will occur before the timeout period (usually 2 minutes).

Comment: The domain does resolve to the correct IP address. I tried `telnet auth.mydomain.com 443` and it still says `Connection timed out`, although I can actually ping that IP without any packet loss. To be on the safe side, I disabled all rules in the Unifi Network firewall settings - and still the same thing. Also, I haven't added any specific rules in Docker to block outgoing connections. Where should I look for something like this?

Comment: Then it seems pretty clear you have a DNS issue. make sure the IP returned for auth.mydomain.com has a running service on 443.

Comment: I have made sure of that. There are other services which are perfectly available on that same port behind that same reverse proxy. Besides, as I pointed out, I can access said URL just fine from any other device, be it on the same subnet or outside.